# The topological closure $\overline{X}$ of a subset $X \subset \mathbb{A}_k^n$ is equal to the set $Z(I(\overline{X}))$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, solution-verification, zariski-topology

My question is on the topological closure of any subset $X$ of the affine space $\mathbb{A}_k^n$. I tried to prove that $\overline{X} = Z(I(X))$. The attempt goes as follows:

Notice that we have the inclusions
$$
X \subset \overline{X} \implies I(\overline{X}) \subset I(X) \implies Z(I(X)) \subset Z(I(\overline{X})),
$$
and, also
$$
X \subset Z(I(X)) \subset Z(I(\overline{X})) = \overline{X},
$$
since $\overline{X}$ is closed. So we just need to show that $Z(I(X)) \supset Z(I(\overline{X}))$. Take $(a_1,\dots,a_n) \in Z(I(\overline{X}))$, then $f(a_1,\dots,a_n) = 0$ for all $f \in I(\overline{X})$, id est, $f(a_1,\dots,a_n) = 0$ for all $(a_1,\dots,a_n) \in \overline{X}$. Since $X \subset \overline{X}$, we have $f(a_1,\dots,a_n) = 0$ for all $(a_1,\dots,a_n) \in X$, then $f(a_1,\dots,a_n) = 0$ for all $f \in I(X)$, ergo $(a_1,\dots,a_n) \in Z(I(X))$. $\blacksquare$

What I am suspicious about is that i did not use the fact that $\overline{X}$ is the smallest closed set containing $X$, because of that I am almost certain it is not correct (I'm specially suspicious about the $f(a_1,\dots,a_n) = 0$ for all $f \in I(X)$ part).

Can you show me where I got wrong and how I could prove the equality $Z(I(X))=Z(I(\overline{X})$? Also, this is probably the hard way of solving it, if there is an easier way, could you explain briefly?

Thank you very much!

Comment: These questions are probably not closely related to each other as to warrant being included in the same post. I'd suggest splitting them up so that each question is in a separate post.

Comment: Ok, I thought I would waste less of your time by clustering them together. Sorry for that, I will edit this one maintaining the first question and I will post the second separately.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured the easier way: Since $Z(I(X))$ is a closed set containing $X$, then $\overline{X} \subset Z(I(X))$. $\blacksquare$

But, still, is it possible to show that $Z(I(\overline{X})) = Z(I(X))$ directly?

Comment: $I(\overline{X}) = I(X)$ ( $\subseteq$ is obvious and $\supseteq$ is because if a function vanishes on $X$ then it vanishes on the closure of $X$.)